# How to add multiple address spaces while creating Azure VNET using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

**Objective**: Trying to create Azure VNet (virtual network) with multiple address spaces with Terraform aka this vnet should be created with 4 address spaces

Code that I am using:

**`main.tf:`**

```
    #-------------------------------------
    # VNET Creation - Default is "true"
    #-------------------------------------
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
      name                = lower("vnet-${var.hub_vnet_name}-${var.location}")
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
      address_space       = [var.vnet_address_space]
      dns_servers         = [var.dns_servers]
      tags                = merge({ "ResourceName" = 
lower("vnet-${var.hub_vnet_name}-${var.location}") }, var.tags, )
```

**`variable.tf`**

```
variable "vnet_address_space" {
  description = "The address space to be used for the Azure virtual network."
  default     = ["10.350.0.0/24","10.351.0.0/20","10.352.0.0/24","10.353.0.0/24"]
}
```

**`terraform.tfvars`**

```
"vnet_address_space":["10.250.0.0/24","10.251.0.0/20","10.252.0.0/24","10.253.0.0/24"]
```

**`Error I am getting:`**

Error:

```
 Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 71, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet":
│   71:   address_space       = [var.vnet_address_space]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.vnet_address_space is tuple with 4 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "address_space": element 0: string required.
```

Please let me know what mistake I am doing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var.vnet_address_space` is already a list. So it should be:

```
address_space       = var.vnet_address_space
```

Comment: Thanks for guidance, Let me give a try

Comment: Hi @Marcin I am getting now `Error: creating/updating Virtual Network: (Name "vnet-vnet-abc-hub-" / Resource Group "rg-orp-vnet"): network.VirtualNetworksClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="NetcfgInvalidIPAddress" Message="IP address is not valid '[]'." Details=[]
│ 
│   with azurerm_virtual_network.vnet,
│   on main.tf line 66, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet":
│   66: resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet"` any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: @asp This is a new issue. For some reason your `var.vnet_address_space` (or other variable used) is empty. I would suggest making a new question for that with relevant details.

Comment: really wonder why i am getting it empty tough my tfvars file have it. Not sure which part I am missing, I have posted all parts used in my code... Ok will try to make a new post...

Comment: @asp It could be other variable. What is `var.dns_servers`? You haven't showed any more info. As I said, this is a new issue.

Comment: `var.dns_servers` is empty list by default since I dont have any custom dns server.  as per documentation its optional, I will try to comment it and run it

Comment: now I get past error and now error happening at creating subnet..I will create a new post thanks for guidance

Comment: @asp Glad that my answer helped you overcome your original problem reported.